# How to take only index 0 of a list of a pandas dataframe and create a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list

In resume:

i have a Dataframe like this in python pandas:

```
Code  Name
13    [Robert, RoBert, robert, robert man]
2     [Barbie, BarBie, barbie, barbie womam]
5     [ShibA, Shiba, Shibba, shiba dog]
100   [HusKYE, huskye, Huskye, huskye dog]
```

I want to transform it into this:

```
Code  Name
13    Robert
2     Barbie
5     ShibA
100   HusKYE
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply). `df['First_Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda names: names[0])`